# How to calculate the area of $\triangle ABC$ when the distance from $BC$ to the circumcircle at $G$ is 10?

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, area

[image]

> $\triangle ABC$ is right angle triangle and its circumcenter is $O$.
> $G$ is a point where $BC$ is tangent to the incircle. The
> perpendicular distance from $BC$ to circumcircle at $G$ is 10. How to
> calculate the area of $\triangle ABC$?

I have tried to prove if the incenter, circumcenter and orthocenter are collinear but failed. I couldn't find what was special about the point $G$. What would be the correct approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Hint use the tangents . They are the key to the problem

Comment: Hint: Join $BD$ and $DC$ to get $BG\times GC=100$

Comment: @Anand is the area 100?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Let $|BC|=a$, $|AC|=b$, $|AB|=c$,
$|GE|=|DE|$.

The distances to the tangent point $G$ of the incircle are

\begin{align}
|BG|&=\tfrac12(a+c-b)
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
|CG|&=\tfrac12(a+b-c)
\tag{2}\label{2}
,
\end{align}

and by
[the power of the point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point)
$G$ w.r.t the circumcircle,

\begin{align}
|BG|\cdot|CG|&=|DG|\cdot|EG|=|DG|^2=100
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
|BG|\cdot|CG|&=\tfrac14(a+c-b)(a+b-c)
=\tfrac14(a^2-(c-b)^2)
=\tfrac14(b^2+c^2-(c-b)^2)
=\tfrac12\,bc
\tag{4}\label{4}
,
\end{align}

hence, the area of $\triangle ABC$ is $100$.

Comment: how did you get the lengths of BG and CG?

Comment: @C Squared: It's a very well-known property 
of the tangent points of the incircle in any triangle,
which can be easily deduced. Consider all three tangent points. 
Let the distances from the vertices $A,B,C$ to any adjacent tangent point be $x,y$ and $z$.
Then $x+y=c,y+z=a,z+x=b$, find $x,y,z$.

Answer (score 2):

Euler's theorem states that the distance d between the circumcentre and incentre of a triangle is given by $d^{2}=R(R-2r)$.

Let $I$ be a center of incircle. We have

$$ OI^2 = IG^2 + OG^2$$ or $$OG^2 = OI^2 - IG^2 = R(R-2r)-r^2.$$

On other hand, we have $$OD^2 = DG^2 + OG^2$$ or $$R^2 = DG^2 + (R^2-2Rr - r^2)$$
Then $$DG^2 = r(2R+r) = 100.$$

Note that $S_{ABC} = \frac{r(AB+BC+CA)}{2} = \frac{r(2r+4R)}{2}=r(2R+r).$

So we have $S_{ABC} = 100$.